# Filter imported dataset in azure data factory

Tags: filter, azure-data-factory

I have a JSON file which I need to filter down to only show the data for the last 2 days.

Is there a way to add an expression to do this so that I can sink the dataset which contains data from the last 2 days?

Also, can it be done using the filter option in a pipeline or am I required to create a dataflow for this sort of problem?

Comment: I would use a dataflow for this since you're going to need to parse/inspect the data inside the file and possibly traverse hierarchies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm agree with @Mark Kromer, you should use Data flow. It has the filter active and can achieve that easier.

The filter needs to parse/inspect the data inside the file and possibly traverse hierarchies.

I just make a example which filter the data `date > "2020-12-01"`:
[image]

Filter:
[image]

Output preview:
[image]

Filter based on your data column to keep the data in last 2 days.